# Ensure that the max element in a matrix is less than $\lambda$

Tags: matrices

If I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and I want to scale the matrix $A$ (let us notate the scaled $A$ by $A'$) such that $A'_{ij} \le \lambda, \lambda > 0 $. How to scale the matrix $A$?

Here is an attempt I made. It breaks if $\lambda \in (0,1):$

$$A' = \frac{1}{\max(\lambda, \|A \|_\infty)} A$$

where $\| \cdot \|_\infty $ is the infinity norm.

Comment: What kind of function? Your attempt makjes little sense to me. You want $f(A) \leq \lambda$ (which suggests you consider a function with calues in the real numbers). On the other hand, your proposal is a matrix-valued function. What exactly are you looking for? Please state the codomain and the requirements on the functions precisely.

Comment: @QuantumSpace see the edit please

Comment: It is still not clear to me. How does $f(A) \le \lambda$ makes sense? The left hand side is a matrix, the right hand side a scalar. Maybe you mean $\lambda I$ instead of $\lambda?$ Also, is the matrix $A$ fixed or not?

Comment: @QuantumSpace the inequality defined as $A_{ij} \le \lambda$ for all i and j. If you still are not comfortable, I would write it as $max f(A) \le \lambda$ where $max$ returns the maximum element in the matrix. $A$ is any matrix.

Comment: You haven't given any other requirements on $f$ other than its domain, codomain, and the inequality. It is trivial to come up with $f$ that satisfy all three, such as $f_{ij}(M) = \lambda$ for all $M, i, j$. I'm sure that solution is worthless for you, but there is no reason in your post to reject it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh I see. I edited the post. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_{\max} = \max_{ij} A_{ij}$. If $a_{\max} \leq 0$ then we are done. Otherwise suppose that $a_{\max} > 0$ and then
$$\hat{A} := \frac{1}{a_{\max}}A$$
is a matrix such that every entry is no larger than $1$. Then define
$$A' := \lambda \hat{A} = \frac{\lambda}{ a_{\max}} A,$$ for some $\lambda \geq 0$. This matrix will have every entry no larger than $\lambda$. Indeed, we have
$$
A_{ij}' = \frac{\lambda}{a_{\max}} A_{ij} = \lambda \frac{A_{ij}}{a_{\max}} \leq \lambda \times 1 = \lambda
$$